# PHP to VFP. Error: Could not convert string to unicode

Tags: php, unicode, visual-foxpro

I have written a code to get images from instagram and saving data to DB using the code below:

Calling this PHP file from the command line, I am getting this error:

> Warning: Unknown: Could not convert string to Unicode: 'No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page'.
>   PHP Fatal Error

This code is executing on Windows 7 64 bit. Please help me with this.

Comment: Which line does the error occur in

Comment: Warning: Unknown: Could not convert string to Unicode: 'No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page'. Php Fatal Error

Comment: when saving the data to vfp, 
$conn->Execute($dd);

Comment: Please point out the exact line in your question. You can edit the question

Comment: There is the issue about unicode,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my pc's setting to english, now it is working